# Nswag client generator tries to generate when azure secrets are added

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-keyvault, nswag

In the project I am involved with now, we are using `dotnet-nswag.dll` to generate a typescript api client. I am now trying to switch from using local secrets to secrets stored in azure key vault (I hope to simplify new developers' entry to the project). I however bumped into a problem, that when I use something like below:

```cs
builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((ctx, cfg) =>
{
    if (ctx.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        var keyVaultEndpoint = new Uri(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DevEnv_KVUri"));
        cfg.AddAzureKeyVault(keyVaultEndpoint, new DefaultAzureCredential());
    }
});
```

I no longer can generate the nswag typescript api client. My investigation led me to the discovery that nswag fails becasue `DevEnd_KVUri` does not exists at the generation time. I have this env var added in my `launchSettigns.json` and it is available when I test my app. However, I would like to instruct nswag not to try to include whatever is triggering it to also go through that key vault endpoint.

If I hard-code the url (and it is a KeyVault url that I have access to), then the generation passes. Generated client does not have any endpoints pointing to my hard-coded url. However I do not like the solution, where I have to hard-code (not even fake but a working one) my key vault address.

Unfortunately, I did not find any solution to my problem.

Edit 1:
The command that executes generation:

```bash
dotnet "C:\Users\myname\.nuget\packages\nswag.msbuild\13.16.0\build\../tools/Net50/dotnet-nswag.dll" run nswag.json /variables:Configuration=Debug`
```

The exception thrown by the generator when no url is provided

```cs
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
 ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'uriString')
   at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)
   at Lib.KeyVault.Extensions.IWebHostBuilderExtensions.<>c.<UseKeyVault>b__0_1(HostBuilderContext ctx, IConfigurationBuilder bld) in C:\dotnet\net\lib\Lib.KeyVault.Extensions\IWebHostBuilderExtensions.cs:line 50
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.BuildAppConfiguration()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
   at NSwag.Commands.ServiceProviderResolver.GetServiceProvider(Assembly assembly) in /_/src/NSwag.Commands/HostApplication.cs:line 61
   at NSwag.Commands.Generation.AspNetCore.AspNetCoreToOpenApiGeneratorCommandEntryPoint.Process(String commandContent, String outputFile, String applicationName) in /_/src/NSwag.Commands/Commands/Generation/AspNetCore/AspNetCoreToOpenApiGeneratorCommandEntryPoint.cs:line 27
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Span`1& arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
   at NSwag.AspNetCore.Launcher.Program.Main(String[] args) in /_/src/NSwag.AspNetCore.Launcher/Program.cs:line 132
System.InvalidOperationException: Swagger generation failed with non-zero exit code '1'.
   at NSwag.Commands.Generation.AspNetCore.AspNetCoreToSwaggerCommand.RunAsync(CommandLineProcessor processor, IConsoleHost host) in /_/src/NSwag.Commands/Commands/Generation/AspNetCore/AspNetCoreToOpenApiCommand.cs:line 231
   at NSwag.Commands.NSwagDocumentBase.GenerateSwaggerDocumentAsync() in /_/src/NSwag.Commands/NSwagDocumentBase.cs:line 275
   at NSwag.Commands.NSwagDocument.ExecuteAsync() in /_/src/NSwag.Commands/NSwagDocument.cs:line 81
   at NSwag.Commands.Document.ExecuteDocumentCommand.ExecuteDocumentAsync(IConsoleHost host, String filePath) in /_/src/NSwag.Commands/Commands/Document/ExecuteDocumentCommand.cs:line 85
   at NSwag.Commands.Document.ExecuteDocumentCommand.RunAsync(CommandLineProcessor processor, IConsoleHost host) in /_/src/NSwag.Commands/Commands/Document/ExecuteDocumentCommand.cs:line 32
   at NConsole.CommandLineProcessor.ProcessSingleAsync(String[] args, Object input)
   at NConsole.CommandLineProcessor.ProcessAsync(String[] args, Object input)
   at NSwag.Commands.NSwagCommandProcessor.ProcessAsync(String[] args) in /_/src/NSwag.Commands/NSwagCommandProcessor.cs:line 61
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately no.